# Tab-complete herbstclient with fish shell?

Tags: fish

I'd like to be able to simply type `herb` and then press tab and have fish-shell tab-complete it to `herbstclient`. I've tried looking it up, but every result I can find has to do with overiding fish's autocomplete with tab rather than ctrl + f.

Do I need to create a fish script for this? If so, what should it look like and where should I put it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that is a command you want an abbreviation: `abbr herb herbstclient`. Although you don't use [tab] to complete an abbreviation; you have to press [space] or [enter]. Note that the expansion can consist of multiple tokens. For example, this is one of my most often used abbreviations: `abbr -a -g -- gcm 'git checkout master'`. Also, abbreviations only get expanded in the command position; i.e., start of line or after a pipe, `|`, or semicolon. If you want that expansion elsewhere in a command line there are ways to achieve that but it's a bit more complicated.